# HTML code differences when trying to parse code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, pycharm, html-parsing

I am having an issue with HTML parsing a website using Selenium. I have the parent variable (individual message), and their nested classes I am trying to extract (name, content, timestamp). The issue arises when I try and run the program through PyCharm I get the error saying parent variable can't be found. Upon doing `html = driver.page_source`. I do not see the variable along with other surrounding code. This is odd because when I inspect element I see the parent variable as clear as day! I also double checked by cutting out all the HTML directly from my browser starting from first line and when I search I also could not find parent variable. I do not know why it hides or where it goes when I parse. From what I saw there are two `!doctype html` with the nested one being cached generated, another theory is it being a dynamic webpage with it being a chatroom and all. The code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.website.com/chat")
driver.find_element("name", "val[login]").send_keys("email@gmail.com")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("name", "val[password]").send_keys("Password")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element("id", "_submit").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)
driver.get("https://website.com/chat")
time.sleep(60)

messages = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "message flex-property msg-box  ")

for message in messages:
    username = message.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "username").text
    content = message.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "content").text
    print(username,content)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
No such element exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
line 20, in <module>
    messages = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "message flex-property msg-box  ")

line 740, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]

line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".message flex-property msg-box  "}
```

Comment: Instead of describing your code, show us the relevant parts.

Comment: Are you sure `"message flex-property msg-box  "` is correct and not `"message flex-property msg-box"`?